# Return list of affected indices from in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to write a query which will search across all indices in Elastisearch and return me a list of all indices where at least one document meets query requirements.

For now I`m getting top 2000 documents and distinct them by index name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search across all indices in the elastcsearch, you can use the [**_all**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) option.

You can try similar to following, to get the indices which gets hits for the query

```
POST _all/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "you search criteia"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Most APIs that refer to an index parameter support execution across multiple indices, using simple test1,test2,test3 notation (or **_all** for all indices)

You can extract the index name from the result set which will be present under **_index**

sample result:

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "index-name",
         }
       ]
```